# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, type-conversion

I'm failing to cast a `Map<String, dynamic>` into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>`. What is the best way to do this?

Note that I'm using the advanced analysis options in my `analysis_options.yaml`:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - extension-methods
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

I tried

```dart
var de = Map<String, Map<String, String>>.from((json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('lang/de.json'))) as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

and

```dart
var de = (json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('lang/de.json')) as Map<String, dynamic>).cast<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

and

```dart
var de = Map.castFrom<String, dynamic, String, Map<String, String>>((json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('lang/de.json'))) as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

All attempts raised the following runtime error: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' in type cast`

What is the best way to this? I think this can be done by iterating through the map but if these are very large, this is an expensive operation. Is there any way to cast them without iterating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to cast to the appropriate type when dealing with nested data like this.

There was a similar discussion here about casting nested lists: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1574

I think iterating over the data in some fashion is the only thing you can do in this situation.

One possible solution:

```dart
final data = await rootBundle.loadString('lang/de.json');
final Map<String, Map<String, String>> de = {
  for (final entry in (json.decode(data) as Map).entries)
    entry.key as String: {
      for (final e in (entry.value as Map).entries)
        e.key as String: e.value as String,
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a shame that dart do not provide any better tools for that. This overhead in tearms of code and runtime performance is huge. So I think I'll disable the advanced analysis options to avoid those things. Looks like this is trade off: performance vs code quality.